# Strange characters with polish letters in PHP

Tags: php

I've got this piece of code:

```php
      if (self::$username == "Borsucza Łapa.") {
        die("tak");
      } else {
        echo self::$username . "<br />";
        echo "Borsucza Łapa.";
      }
```

The condition is not valid, and the output from else statement is:

```
Borsucza Łapa.
Borsucza �apa.
```

What's that sign and how to turn it to an `Ł` sign?

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to utf8_encode()?

echo utf8_encode(self::$username);

Comment: `utf8_encode(self::$username)` returns `Borsucza Åapa`

Comment: is your doctype ok? <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Comment: `utf8_encode()` is rarely useful. It's sole purpose is to convert a string in ISO-8859-1 encoding to UTF-8 encoding. Given that there's no evidence of the string being ISO-8859-1, and there's no Ł in that character set, it is not going to be of any help.